# А можно ли искать в json

Tags: json, php

Есть вот такой список

```
 [{
    "pos": 1,
    "uid": "44420575",
    "rating": "14130271"
}, {
    "pos": 2,
    "uid": "24055142",
    "rating": "1657068"
}, {
    "pos": 3,
    "uid": "29846213",
    "rating": "1592081"
}]
```

Нужно получить rating там где uid 24055142. Можно ли как то так искать?

Comment: если можно поменять структуру, то я бы индексом массива сделал uid. искать конечно можно, куча функций для обхода массивов в php есть,

Comment: Увы поменять нельзя. А как поиск можно реализовать?

Comment: Хотел заюзать либу **PHP linq**, но что-то не взлетела у меня выборка из обычного ассоциативного массива, так что просто оставлю здесь, что такое понятие как LINQ есть не только в С#, и можно делать очень удобные выборки объектов.

Comment: махнуть в массив, найти элемент, конвертнуть его json и вернуть уже как json

Answer (score 4):

**[Посмотреть на пример](http://ideone.com/NHZIro)**.

```
$json = '[{
    "pos": 1,
    "uid": "44420575",
    "rating": "14130271"
}, {
    "pos": 2,
    "uid": "24055142",
    "rating": "1657068"
}, {
    "pos": 3,
    "uid": "29846213",
    "rating": "1592081"
}]';
```

**Вариант А:**

```
$a = json_decode($json, TRUE);    
foreach ($a as $value) {
    if ($value['uid'] === '24055142') {
        echo $value['rating'];
        break;   
    }
}
```

**Вариант Б:**

```
$a = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$segment = array_shift(array_filter($a, function($v){
    return $v['uid'] === '24055142';
}));
echo $segment['rating'];
```

Comment: Но что-то не работает

Comment: Мягко говоря, плохо пытались. Я не удивлен, что не работает.  
1)  **$json2**  
1а) кавычки закрыты неправильно  
1б) некорректный json  
2) foreach ($json as $value) - цикл **foreach** работает с массивами, а не со строкой в формате json.  
3) $value->uid - почему вы к элементу массива обращаетесь как к методу объекта?

Comment: @VenZell: +1 за честный парсинг.

Comment: в foreach думаю неплохо было бы break поставить после нахождения элемента

Answer (score 0):

Вот PHP функция под твой масив. передаем json и uid ответ получаем rating

```
function ratingByUID($uid, $json) {
    foreach(json_decode($json, true) as $i) {
        if ($i['uid'] == $uid) {
            return $i['rating'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
echo ratingByUID(44420575, '[{"pos":1,"uid":"44420575","rating":"14130271"},{"pos":2,"uid":"24055142","rating":"1657068"},{"pos":3,"uid":"29846213","rating":"1592081"}]');
```